# How to setup Traefik and shiny server (dockerized) on AWS ubuntu with Custom SSL certs files?

Tags: docker-compose, docker-swarm, traefik

I am trying to setup Traefik and dockerized shiny server (with replicas) on Ubuntu. but I am unable to set it up.

The resource details on which I need to setup.

- Server: AWS EC2 instance (single) i.e ec2.xxxxxxxxxxxxx
- provided domain: abc.xxxgateway.com(for traefik),xyz.xxxgateway.com(shiny-server)
- SSL file: SSL.cert, SSL.key

I tried to follow this tutorial but unsuccessful to set it up. only traefik is up on abc.xxxgateway.com but 404 error on xyz.xxxgateway.com for the shiny-server.

Comment: https://www.databentobox.com/2020/05/31/shinyproxy-with-docker-swarm/